# Passing in Int to a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to create a hidden field on my View. The View should just accept an int (Not a model).

My controller method to create the view is simply:

```
public ActionResult BookingHistory(int id)
{
   return View(id);
}
```

So my model on the view is defined as:

```
@model Int32
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Form History</h2>
```

How do I then create a hidden field for this field?

`@Html.HiddenFor(Model)` ?

(This failed)
But I need to assign a name or something to it. How can I have a hidden field on the form, with the value passed in?

Comment: I'm trying that, but get an error "Value cannot be null or empty". What id/name would it assign to the hidden field, by using this method?

Comment: I fixed it. Using this instead: @Html.Hidden("patientId", Model, new { @id="patientId"})

Answer (score 1):

Hidden field created via this syntax.

```
@Html.Hidden("patientId", Model, new { @id="patientId"})
```